# Hide GridLayout column and remaining column spacing

Tags: java, swt

**tl;dr** Is there a good way to hide a column in a `GridLayout` and also hide the remaining column spacing on the parent `Composite`?

---

I have a composite with several columns in a `GridLayout`. One column is a `Composite` with a `StackLayout` so that given some action I can hide/show that `Composite`.

For example:
[image]

To do the hiding/showing I've been setting the `exclude` attribute on the `GridData` and the `topControl` attribute on the `StackLayout`:

```
// To hide
stackLayout.topControl = null;
stackComposite.setVisible(false);
((GridData) stackComposite.getLayoutData()).exclude = true;
```

Now, when I hide the middle `Composite`, I see extra space appear at the far end of the row.

[image]

This is presumably because the `GridLayout` on the base `Composite` still has the same number of columns, so what we see is a column with 0 width, and the specified column spacing on either side.

To fix this I've come up with several (not-ideal) solutions:

1. Decrement/increment the number of columns when hiding/showing.
2. Instead of using the `exclude` attribute, we override the `Composite` with the `StackLayout` and change the `computeSize(...)` functions to either return 0, or compute the real size depending on whether we want it to appear or not. (This is by far my least favorite option and I feel bad even writing it)
3. Set the `horizontalSpacing` on the base `Composite` to 0, and instead using the spacing inside each columns `Composite` to dictate the spacing. It would look like this when hidden:

[image]

**Option 1** has been the most enticing so far, however there's an clear drawback here when trying to keep code modular. For example, if the `Composite` for each column is setup by some reusable component, decrementing/incrementing a column count depends on that component knowing that its parent `Composite` has a `GridLayout` - not a safe assumption!

**Option 2** I flat-out do not like.

**Option 3** isn't horrible, however it still feels like a misuse of spacing and margins. Plus, back to the point of modularity, the other column components would be responsible spacing which affects the larger view, instead of letting the larger view dictate the spacing.

So my question comes down to: **is there another option that's better than these three?**

---

MCVE used to get the images above:

```
public class MCVE {

    final Display display;
    final Shell shell;

    public MCVE() {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        final Composite baseComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        baseComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));
        baseComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        baseComposite.setBackground(new Color(display, new RGB(125, 125, 255)));

        final Composite contentComposite1 = new Composite(baseComposite, SWT.NONE);
        contentComposite1.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        contentComposite1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        final Label contentLabel1 = new Label(contentComposite1, SWT.NONE);
        contentLabel1.setText("I stretch to fill available space!");

        final Composite stackComposite = new Composite(baseComposite, SWT.NONE);
        final StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
        stackComposite.setLayout(stackLayout);
        stackComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, true));

        final Composite stackContentComposite = new Composite(stackComposite, SWT.NONE);
        stackContentComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        stackContentComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        final Label stackContentLabel = new Label(stackContentComposite, SWT.NONE);
        stackContentLabel.setText("I can disappear and reappear!");

        stackLayout.topControl = stackContentComposite;

        final Composite contentComposite3 = new Composite(baseComposite, SWT.NONE);
        contentComposite3.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        contentComposite3.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, true));
        final Label contentLabel3 = new Label(contentComposite3, SWT.NONE);
        contentLabel3.setText("I live on the end :(");

        final Button flipButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        flipButton.setText("Flip");
        flipButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
                if (stackLayout.topControl == null) {
                    stackLayout.topControl = stackContentComposite;
                    ((GridData) stackComposite.getLayoutData()).exclude = false;
                    // ((GridLayout) baseComposite.getLayout()).numColumns++;
                    stackComposite.setVisible(true);
                    baseComposite.layout(true, true);
                } else {
                    stackLayout.topControl = null;
                    ((GridData) stackComposite.getLayoutData()).exclude = true;
                    // ((GridLayout) baseComposite.getLayout()).numColumns--;
                    stackComposite.setVisible(false);
                    baseComposite.layout(true, true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void run() {
        shell.setSize(600, 115);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        new MCVE().run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any other way.

Option 1 is definitely what I would use and is used widely by Eclipse code (buttons on the dialog button bar for example).

Since you are already assuming the control layout data is `GridData` it is safe to assume the parent layout is `GridLayout` (setting `GridData` as layout data on some other layout will generally give a run time error).

Comment: Good points - I hadn't thought to explicitly check Eclipse code for how this is handled (A quick search turned up this [`ViewSettingsDialog`](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/eclipse/ui/preferences/ViewSettingsDialog.java.html) code which does something very similar). Thanks for the reminder about the relationship with the parent there too, that confused me for the longest time :)